# Read jars from lib folder in grails

Tags: grails, jar, grails-2.0

I want to parse an excel file using the [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) to boot strap some data in development mode into my grails 2.0.1 application.

I've tried to use the Grails [excel-import plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import) but the [plugin uninstalls automatically when I execute run-app](https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import/issues/4).

Because of that I decided to got ahead without the plugin for now. First I have copied the next jars into the grails application lib folder

```
$ls -la lib
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

I've read that I should declare the dependency in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`. So, I added the next:

```
   dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        compile ('org.apache.poi:poi:3.7', 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.7')  

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }
```

However when I execute run-app the application is still not able to find the jars.

```
grails> run-app
| Compiling 76 source files

| Compiling 30 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
UMEExcelImporter.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
 @ line 8, column 1.
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
   ^

UMEExcelImporter.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
   ^

UMEExcelImporter.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
 @ line 9, column 1.
   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
```

I am not using any IDE. Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Does any of copied jar contains this classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POI jars are on public Maven repo's so try this:

1. Remove the jars from your lib folder
2. Clean your build with:  `grails clean`
3. In you BuildConfig.groovy ensure that the "repositories" closure has "`mavenCentral()`" included/uncommented
4. Your dependency looks ok (I have not confirmed it) so now try the run-app

HTH

Answer (score 3):

instead of adding compile dependency, try adding runtime dependency as follows.

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        runtime ('org.apache.poi:poi:3.7', 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.7')  

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
}
```