# Include POI libraries in grails app

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-poi

I have a grails app and the groovy under /src/groovy has import statements for Java POI HSSF
for example

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle
```

What is the best way to add POI to my grails app so its deployed with the war. I tried adding the jars to /lib and then adding them as runtime dependencies in BuilConfig.groovy.

```
dependencies {
     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
     runtime 'poi-3.9-20121203'
     runtime 'poi-ooxml-3.9'
     runtime 'poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9'
     runtime 'xml-apis-ext-1.3.04'
     runtime 'xmlbeans-2.3.0'
     runtime 'xmlpull-1.1.3.1'
     runtime 'xstream-1.4.7'
}
```

I also tried adding it as a compile plugin this way

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.13"       
        compile ":excel-import:1.0.0"
}
```

Both generate this error on grails war

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
```

EDIT: my repositories has maven but still complains about missing class def [Read jars from lib folder in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452090/read-jars-from-lib-folder-in-grails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While adding any dependency or plugin in Grails, maven artifact semantics has to be followed instead if the plain jar name. For example,

```
runtime 'xmlbeans-2.3.0'
```

should be

```
runtime 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0'
```

which corresponds to

```
runtime '<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>'
```

Same is applicable for all the other dependencies and plugins. Rewrite those one by one and remove all jars from `lib` directory. Clean and compile the app subsequently.